# CSS file not loading even after adding middleware

Tags: css, node.js, express, ejs, middleware

CSS files are not loading and on inspecting element(F12) and going to Networks, my CSS file is not visible.
I have added the middleware

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

and also required path above it.

I have added the middleware, required it and npm installed it too.

My Folder Structure

```
-app.js

-package.json

-package-lock.json

-node_modules

-public

    -stylesheets

        -main.css

-views

    -index.ejs

    -partials

        -header.ejs

        -footer.ejs
```

My Header.ejs file has this and my body containing some text.

`<link href="/stylesheets/main.css">`

My app.js file is

```
var express = require('express');
var request = require('request');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));
```

and my css file changes the color of backgorund, index.ejs file calls the header and footer respectively

```
<% include partials/header%>
```

My css code

```
body{
background-color: purple;
text-align: center;
}
```

My chrome console shows no error and still I am not able to upload my CSS.
Thanks in advance for your inputs.

Comment: What's exactly your code ? in one hand, your public path begins with a '/public', in another in begins without the slash...

Comment: Sorry I have updated it its "/public" at both the places

Comment: Try to go to localhost:yourport/stylesheets/main.css  Does the file show up, if it does than its being served property and its an HTML linking issue    else its a static file issue

Comment: Could you see any warnings in console related to MIME type?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the link tag wrong.
You need to supply `rel` and `type` attributes for it to load the css and parse it properly. Check out the documentation of `link` tag to know more

Comment: Actually I used them but using the tag I was giving a mime type error. After going through a stack overflow the solution to that problem was removing rel and type.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the link tag. You have to specify **rel**, **type** and **href** attributes in your link tag.

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "/stylesheets/main.css" />
```

Comment: Actually I used them but using the tag I was giving a mime type error. After going through a stack overflow the solution to that problem was removing rel and type.

Answer (score 0):

The mater is that your are requesting stylesheet file given an url who will be completed by navigator with the current root path.
For instance, this is your link below.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href = "/stylesheets/main.css" />
```

This is your NodeJS server code.

```js
app.get("/your/root/path", (req, res)=>{

})
```

Your href link will correspond to `/your/root/path/stylesheets/main.css`
I think that it will be your problem.
If so, to correct it, set `<base>` url for static files or don't let your routes path who return views to be in the form `/your/root/path` but instead `/your-root-path`

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get you. I am a beginner. So in my ejs files in the header I should not do any change and use a base tag in header.ejs file is that what you are saying? Or should I put header footer and my other ejs files in a same folder?

Comment: What i wanted to say is that in the header tag, you have to use a base tag like this `<html><head>...<base href="/your/static/root/">...</head>...`. But this is not the best way to resolve this issue. You should use root withought sub path but unique path root like this `/my-root-path-withought-sub-path`.

Comment: Instead of this : ``` app.get('/my/root/path/withought/sub/path', (res,res)=>{...})``` do this ``` app.get('/my-root-path-withought-sub-path', (res,res)=>{...})``` But this is useful only for paths that render views. For paths who doesn't render view, you can define the root path as you want @Mayank